# Sending email using third party software restricting by big mail providers (Gmail, hotmail..)

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, gmail-api, smtpclient

*Hi,*
I made a .net tool that will be distributed with The Software package of our company. and..

This tool mainly send us email with some support information from the customer's servers. but..

Sending those emails by smtp of big email providers (Gmail, hotmail..) sometimes being restricted in spite of I give it all available permissions through their sites..!

- This problem happens with each new installation in a new locations (new internet nodes).

**- The Question is.
    How can i stop gmail, hotmail,... from that extra security options or there is other trusted smtp providers i can depend on?**

Thank you all,
Mohamed Abulnasr

Comment: Why send from their smtp at all? Maybe sendgrid or any other smtp service?

Comment: The point just is for depending on a trusted services provider for the stability of our work. but i'll check your idea. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution :

1- allow less secure option in the gmail, yahoo ... 
like [in Gmail](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
2- constraint sending daily mails not to exceeds 20 or 30 email per day.

3- using using System.Net.Mail instead of System.Web.Mail

4-

first >> `Credentials = new NetworkCredential(...);`

second >> `UseDefaultCredentials = false;`